# Why did Fontane spend almost a decade writing literary or historical accounts of Prussian wars?

Tags: german-language, theodor-fontane

Theodor Fontane is today best remembered as a novelist (and also as a poet). However, all his novels were written in the last two decades of his life. A list of [publications by Fontane](https://www.neuruppin.de/fileadmin/dateien/Kultur/Kultur_Downloads/Liste_der_Werke_Fontanes.pdf) published by his native town Neuruppin contains a section on books about wars ("Kriegsbücher"):

- *Der Schleswig-Holsteinische Krieg im Jahre 1864* (1866; about the [Second Schleswig War or Deutsch-Dänischer Krieg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Schleswig_War) of 1864),
- *Der deutsche Krieg von 1866* (2 volumes, 1870/71; about the [Austro-Prussian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Prussian_War) of 1866),
- *Kriegsgefangen. Erlebtes 1870* (1871; about his experiences as a prisoner of war during the Franco-Prussian war; Fontane wasn't a soldier but collection information for a book about the war),
- *Aus den Tagen der Okkupation, Eine Osterreise durch Nordfrankreich und Elsaß-Lothringen 1871* (2 volumes, 1871; about the same war),
- *Der Krieg gegen Frankreich 1870-1871* (2 volumes, 1873; about the the [Franco-Prussian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Prussian_War) of 1870–1871).

This means that between 1864 and 1873 Fontane spent most of his time writing books about wars. For example, a more recent edition of *Der Krieg gegen Frankreich 1870-1871* (Manesse, 1980s) spans for volumes totalling over 2600 pages, making this his longest work by a wide margin. However, the [English Wikipedia article about the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Fontane#Wars_of_German_Unification) also tells us that

> In his observations he strongly criticized Prussian militarism: "A mere glorification of the military without moral content or elevated aim is nauseating."

If Fontane was so critical of militarism, why did he attach so much importance to this type of writing instead of focussing on poems and novels or his work for newspapers? (Writing about one's own experiences is understandable, so this question is not about *Kriegsgefangen. Erlebtes 1870* but about the non-autobiographical works.)